# Google Maps Places/Geocode API Query String

Tags: c#, .net, google-maps, google-api, google-places-api

I am working with a legacy system that uses the google maps API. I have a query string that we use on the client side with JS, I am wondering how I can make requests to the endpoint from a .NET Web API. Most of the docs say I need an API key, which at my company will require a little more effort to find the username/password associated with the below query string. It looks like it uses a "client" and "channel" key(s) to authenticate the user.

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?client=<client name>&channel=<channel name>&libraries=places,geometry`  <-- This works in JS on the client.

I am looking to request GPS coords (lat/long) from a google API using a street address as a parameter. If anyone knows how I can use the above "client" and "channel" keys and can supply the appropriate API URL string that would be great! I can't find anything in the docs about these keys.

Comment: The GPS coordinates are in the returned map html labeled with tags longitude and latitude.  If you view the response with a text editor you can locate the latitude and longitude values.

Comment: what parameters did you pass to the query string, or would you mind providing a quick example? I'm not sure how to format the query string as I've only used the javascript API functions which just use the base URL

Comment: No parameters are needed.  It is automatically in the response.  Save the response http in a file and then look with a text editor.

Comment: I am looking to search a specific street address (as a query parameter) and get the lat/long of that address

Comment: The API automatically give the lat/lon of the query in the response.  You can verify by comparing against the lat/lon that you get from your cell phone.  Difference may be off by 10 feet.

Comment: If you do not need the entire map you will get back a response quicker.  See : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/requests-geocoding

Comment: what URL are you using? If I send a GET request with https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?client=<client name>&channel=<channel name>&libraries=places,geometry (replaced client name and channel), the only instance of the word "latitude" I can find in the result is "south latitude must be smaller than north latitude"

Comment: It should be lat and lng.  You are getting an error : {UNKNOWN:"UNKNOWN",OK:"OK",INVALID_REQUEST:"INVALID_REQUEST",DOCUMENT_NOT_FOUND:"DOCUMENT_NOT_FOUND",FETCH_ERROR:"FETCH_ERROR",INVALID_DOCUMENT:"INVALID_DOCUMENT",DOCUMENT_TOO_LARGE:"DOCUMENT_TOO_LARGE",LIMITS_EXCEEDED:"LIMITS_EXECEEDED",TIMED_OUT:"TIMED_OUT"}